# Bottom fixed image, as shown in the attached screenshot

Tags: css, background-image, fixed

As shown in the screenshot below, I'd like to put a bottom fixed image, that should appear after (not over) some contents (a logo and a central description text). This image should fit the width of the screen.

I came up with these 2 wrong solutions. First, using **CSS background-size** property:

```
// CSS
.bg {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0%;
    background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}

// HTML part
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Second, using a bit of Javascript and recognizing the window's resize and setting some css properties on an image tag:

```
// JS
        // some magick here...
        if ((win_w / win_h) < ($bg.width() / $bg.height())) {
          $bg.css({height: '100%', width: 'auto'});
        } else {
          $bg.css({width: '100%', height: 'auto'});
        }

// HTML Part (I'm using a shim)
<img class="bg" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="" style="position: relative; left: 0; bottom: 0" />
```

These solutions work, but I don't want the image covering (or be a background of) the logo and the description. Can you help me?

[image: example to achieve]

Comment: why so complicated? Just place picture below the text description and above menu

Comment: That image should fit the window's height. I don't want to scroll down. If I resize the viewport, it should always lock at the top of the footer and adjust its height dynamically.

Comment: You can just do `max-width: 100%;` which will keep the image only as big as its container (in this case the viewport) and when its width changes it will scale properly and maintain its aspect ratio. For IE, you will need a specific stylesheet with `width: 100%;` or a shim for `max-width` css declarations. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps: http://jsfiddle.net/

What I did:

- I first applied a sticky footer: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/
- I then added an extra div for the background (inside the content wrapper, but that should not be necessary)
- I positioned the background div absolute, with a top equal to the height of the content above it (logo and other content you do not want the background behind) and a bottom equal to the height of the footer. Left and right I set to 0 to make it take up the full width.
- I applied the `background-size: contain` you already figured out (still needs prefixing in my example)

The css for the background looks like this:

```
#background {
    background: url(...) no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px; /* height of content above */
    bottom: 50px; /* height of content beneath */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1; /* to position it under the content, but as no content is covering it, you could leave it out as well */
}
```

Normally I am not a big fan of adding empty div's for styling only, but I don't realy see an other solution here. I am even less of a fan of using javascript for something that may mess up your site if it does not get applied (graceful degrade and all), so this is probably the way I would go...

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I'm now trying to integrate it with Stellar.js for a parallax vertical sliding website. But that's another story ;) thank you again